# Eigen SIGSEGV while doing make_pair

Tags: eigen3

I'm updating ~3yr old code and am crashing trying to make a pair out of Vector2d and Matrix2d. Roughly, the code is

```
vector<pair<Vector2d, Matrix2d>> list;
list.resize(points.size());
Vector2d md;
Matrix2d Sd;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    // do stuff to assign elements of md and Sd
    // ...
    list[i] = make_pair(md, Sd); // SIGSEGV on this line
}
```

I found an old [bug](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=213) that looks similar at the final two levels of the stack but that bug is marked as fixed and I confirmed that the fixes from that patch are still in place. I tried making a simple test case but it runs without issue. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Misc info:

- Arch linux
- gcc 6.1.1
- eigen 3.2.9

Here's the backtrace:

```
Thread 7 "flightControlle" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffd7152700 (LWP 12024)]
0x00000000005e846b in _mm_load_pd (__P=0x0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/include/emmintrin.h:119
119       return *(__m128d *)__P;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000005e846b in _mm_load_pd (__P=0x0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/include/emmintrin.h:119
#1  Eigen::internal::pload<double __vector(2)>(Eigen::internal::unpacket_traits<double __vector(2)>::type const*) (from=0x0) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:220
#2  0x000000000060310b in Eigen::internal::ploadt<double __vector(2), 1>(Eigen::internal::unpacket_traits<double __vector(2)>::type const*) (from=0x0) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/GenericPacketMath.h:290
#3  0x0000000000659523 in Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> >::packet<1> (this=0x0, rowId=0, colId=0) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:184
#4  0x00000000006a40fe in Eigen::SwapWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> >::copyPacket<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, 1, 1> (this=0x7fffd7150a30, rowId=0, colId=0, other=...)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Swap.h:100
#5  0x00000000006a1da3 in Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::SwapWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> >, 1>::copyPacketByOuterInner<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, 1, 1> (this=0x7fffd7150a30, outer=0, 
    inner=0, other=...) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:548
#6  0x000000000069fa0e in Eigen::internal::assign_innervec_CompleteUnrolling<Eigen::SwapWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> >, Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, 0, 2>::run (dst=..., src=...)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Assign.h:206
#7  0x000000000069d1f7 in Eigen::internal::assign_impl<Eigen::SwapWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> >, Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, 2, 2, 0>::run (dst=..., src=...)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Assign.h:342
#8  0x000000000069af38 in Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::SwapWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> > >::lazyAssign<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> > (this=0x7fffd7150a30, other=...)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Assign.h:506
#9  0x000000000069856f in Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> >::swap<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> > (this=0x7fffd7150c90, other=...)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:384
#10 0x000000000069591a in Eigen::internal::matrix_swap_impl<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, false>::run (a=..., b=...)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:805
#11 0x0000000000693785 in Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> >::_swap<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> > (this=0x7fffd7150c90, other=...)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:682
#12 0x00000000006923c6 in Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>::swap<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> > (this=0x7fffd7150c90, other=...) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:334
#13 0x00000000006909f9 in Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>::operator=(Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>&&) (this=0x0, 
    other=<unknown type in /home/ryantr/Software/FlightControl/Rover/build/flightController, CU 0x5b3bd1, DIE 0x73ce2f>) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:224
#14 0x000000000068f440 in std::pair<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2> >::operator=(std::pair<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2> >&&) (this=0x0, __p=<unknown type in /home/ryantr/Software/FlightControl/Rover/build/flightController, CU 0x5b3bd1, DIE 0x73e9e5>) at /usr/include/c++/6.1.1/bits/stl_pair.h:319
#15 0x000000000068a452 in ICSL::Quadrotor::VelocityEstimator::calcPriorDistributions (mDeltaList=std::vector of length 1, capacity 1 = {...}, SDeltaList=std::vector of length 1, capacity 1 = {...}, 
    priorDistList=std::vector of length 0, capacity 0, points=std::vector of length 1, capacity 1 = {...}, mv=..., Sv=..., mz=0.050000000000000003, varz=1, focalLength=262.0029296875, dt=0.033000000000000002, 
    omega=...) at /home/ryantr/Software/FlightControl/Rover/src/VelocityEstimator.cpp:566
```

Here's info on the state of md and Sd if that makes a difference:

```
$1 = {<Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> >> = {<Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> >> = {<Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> >> = {<Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, double, double, Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, 3>, false>> = {<Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, 3>> = {<Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, 1>> = {<Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, 0>> = {<Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, m_storage = {m_data = {array = {-6.5748748779296875, 
          -96.418296813964844}}}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) p Sd
$2 = {<Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2> >> = {<Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2> >> = {<Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2> >> = {<Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>, double, double, Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>, 3>, false>> = {<Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>, 3>> = {<Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>, 1>> = {<Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2>, 0>> = {<Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2> >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, m_storage = {m_data = {array = {8947423.3324944824, 110733.5419973651, 
          110733.5419973651, 13614569.654632445}}}}, <No data fields>}
```

Comment: can you confirm that n is less than or equal to points.size()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alignement issue. See this [intro](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html), and in your case this [page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html) will give you the solution. In short, either use non-aligned types:

```
typedef Matrix<double,2,1,DontAlign> Vector2du;
typedef Matrix<double,2,2,DontAlign> Matrix2du;
vector<pair<Vector2du, Matrix2du>> list;
```

or pass an aligned allocator to `std::vector`:

```
vector<pair<Vector2du, Matrix2du>,Eigen::aligned_allocator<pair<Vector2du, Matrix2du>>> list;
```

Comment: Has anything related to this changed in the last couple years? Or just coincidence that I didn't see problems before?

Comment: Nothing changed on our side, but gcc6 enables C++11 by default and thus uses moves instead of deep copies (as seen in backtrace). Compiling with -std=c++03 probably hides the issue.